CLT for exchangeable and symmetric dependent Bernoulli variables
Consider a finite set of $n$ dependent Bernoulli random variables $X_1$, $X_2$, ..., $X_n$ that are symmetric and therefore exchangeable. This means:

Each variable $X_i$ has the same probability of success, denoted by $p = P(X_i = 1)$.
The variance of each variable is $\sigma^2 = Var(X_i)$.
For any pair of distinct variables $X_i$ and $X_j$, their covariance is $\gamma = Cov(X_i, X_j)$.

Under these conditions, does a version of the Central Limit Theorem (CLT) apply? If so, what form does it take, and what are the necessary conditions for it to hold?
